# How to run multiple scene of unity just once during the launching of app

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know how to make something happen only once like a tutorial in a game which appears only when you first start your game and then when your game got saved to a further point it never appears again even when you close your game and start again.

Basically, I have seven scenes but I want to play scene 1-5 just one on the launching of the app and then next time when the user opens the app it directly jumps to the 6th scene

So I want to know how to make something happen only once in a game application.

I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this issue can be easily addressed using PlayerPrefs. You can call PlayerPrefs.SetInt() and PlayerPrefs.GetInt(). Like so:

```
public class SceneRouting : MonoBehaviour {
     void Awake(){
         // -1 means it is not the first time the player launches the game
         // while 1 means it is the first time the player launches the game
         int isFirstTime = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirstTime", -1);

         if(isFirstTime > 0){
             // Here you can load any of these scenes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
         } else {
             // Here you can load scene 6
         }
     }
}
```

You can set the `isFirstTime` variable anywhere in your game flow. Say, for example, when you call the Foo() method, you don't want the game to load scenes 1-5 next time it launches:

```
public void Foo(){
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirstTime", -1);
}
```

Additionally, if you want your game to load scene 6 upon launch, you can set the `isFirstTime` value to 1

Comment: Could you elaborate more please

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). There are multiple ways of using them but this could be one lightweight solution for you.

An example of how to use them would be like this for you;

```
private void Awake()
{
    int tutorialFinishedFlag = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TutorialFinished", 0);

    if(tutorialFinishedFlag == 0)
    {
        ShowScenesOneToFive();
    }
    else
    {
        ShowSceneSix();
    }
}
```

And when you've finished showing them the first 5 scenes, you can set the PlayerPref like so;

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TutorialFinished", 1);
```